# php and $_GET array

Tags: php, html

I have submitted some code to the redirected url and now trying to use this to echo some information out but can't figure out where I am going wrong.

I have the following code:

```
<?php $login_attempt = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['login_attempt']);
    if ($login_attempt) == '1'{
    return 'failed';
    }
?>
```

all I want to do is if the url has `$login_attempt=1` I want to return the message 'failed' to the page.

Comment: echo, not return and there's no reason to use mysql_real_escape_string() here

Comment: Why are you escaping that parameter if you are not using it as part of an SQL query? How is the parameter set? There are too many unknowns here.

Comment: im getting this error message on the page Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL in /home/content/52/8417952/html/login.php on line 48

Answer (score 2):

There is no point of escaping anything if it doesn't enter anywhere important (like a database).

```
<?php 
    if ($_GET['login_attempt'] == '1') {
        echo 'failed';
    }
?>
```

Also, you have a problem in your `if` statement, that's corrected in the code above. Be sure to include **all** of the condition inside of parenthesis, and not just one side of the equality check.

Also, if you wish to display something on the screen, you should `echo` it, not `return`.

Comment: echoing instead of returning isn't the only thing I changed in the code. Read the answer thoroughly to understand what I've done.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
 if ($login_attempt == '1'){
    echo 'failed';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Your error in $login_attempt == '1':

```
<?php $login_attempt = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['login_attempt']);
    if ($login_attempt == '1'){
        echo 'failed';
        return false;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned you have several problems but the syntax error comes from this:

```
if ($login_attempt) == '1'{
```

it should be

```
if ($login_attempt == '1') {
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont u think if ($login_attempt) == '1' should be something like this ($login_attempt == '1')  Sorry...many others also suggested this :P

Answer (score 0):

At the first, I must tell you that you have a mistake in your IF condition. You typed == outside of ().
In addition, you have to be aware of status of setting your variable through your URL. Check the code below. In this code, I made a function to check the status. Default status is true, and we will check it just for a negative condition. I hope it could be useful for you:

```
<?php
function check() {
   if (isset($_GET['login_attempt'])) {
      $login_attempt = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['login_attempt']);
      if ($login_attempt == '1') {
         return false;
      } else {
         return true;
      }
   } else {
      return true;
   }
}
if (!check()) echo('Error Message');
?>
```